# Setting up Content Delivery for the sample single-machine installation for SDL Web 8

Tags: web8

getting error while running this script under Powershell :-

[image]

```
& '\.quickinstall.ps1 -license FILE -enable-discovery -enable-deployer -enable-preview -enable-session'
```

and actual command ran =>

```
PS C:\SDLWeb\cdinstall\resources\quickinstall> & '\.quickinstall.ps1 C:\Installation\SDL Web 8\VMSDLWEB8\cd_licenses -enable-discovery -enable-deployer -enable-preview -enable-session'
```

where file path => given the cd license path

Comment: This actually seems as a documentation defect, as the sample is wrong - it should be `& .\quickinstall.ps1` - the `.` and the `\\` are reversed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a typo in the powershell script.

How about you separate out your powershell commmand like this:

> .\quickinstall.ps1 -license 'C:\Installation\SDL Web 8\VMSDLWEB8\cd_licenses'
>   -enable-discovery -enable-deployer -enable-preview -enable-session

For more details on what parameters can be passed read here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5A13B9C9-CB06-4847-BD0C-05F7AC37335C

Answer (score 2):

What I can see it is a typo in the powershell. You have missed to put the

> -license

attribute before the FILE.

Here is the command for your reference -

```
& '.\quickinstall.ps1 -license FILE -enable-discovery -enable-deployer
-enable-preview -enable-session'
```

where FILE is the full path to, and filename of, your Content Delivery license file.